# output of the Program, in c++,&int to char* casting

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, char, int

Can somebody explain the output of the following program:

```
int main()
{
    int i=512;
    char *c=(char*)&i;
    c[0]=1;
    cout<<"i is:"<<i<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output is:513

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: formally, that is UB, and depends on the platform

Comment: I'm proud to find a duplicate.

Comment: @BЈовић Why would that be UB?

Comment: @jrok: breaks aliasing rules ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Oh, nice :)

Comment: @PaulR Aliasing through a char pointer is legal.

Comment: the output is fixed in case the architecture and the compiler is knowm, but i was not able to understand the output...

Comment: @MarounMaroun, can u give me the link of the duplicate ....

Comment: @sandeepsandha It's above your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of your program [unspecified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior). In practice, it depends on the endianness of your platform and the width of the `int` type.

Your platform is [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian). Let's for simplicity assume that `int` is 32 bits wide.

`512`<sub>10</sub> is `0x00000200` in hex. This is stored in memory as

```
00 02 00 00
```

Your code modifies the first byte to `01`. This changes the `int` to `0x00000201`, which is `513` decimal.

Comment: This is implementation specific value. Aliasing with `char` is explicit exception to strict aliasing.

Comment: Why is it undefined behavior? As long as the endianess is known, I don't see why it should be not well-defined what's happening. Can you explain why it is UB then?

Comment: I've reworded the answer. I believe it is correct now. Let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: Well, if it *really* is UB then the previous version was correct. I don't know if it is UB, I only wanted to know why you thought it would be.

Comment: @leemes *As long as the endianess is known.* Where in the standard is endianness mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

The program exhibits unspecified behaviour, dependent on the architecture of the machine. To predict and reason about the output requires knowledge of the compiler and the target architecture.

Comment: A reason would be nice.

Comment: @leemes A reason for what? A reason as to why this is UB?

Comment: Exactly. Can you give a quote of some paragraph? Or what *exactly* about this program is UB?

Comment: @leemes for a start, what reinterpret_cast (or c-style cast) does is UB

Comment: @leemes I don't know whether or not the program formally exhibits UB.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation:

```
int main()
{
    /* Creates int equal to 512 */
    int i=512;

    /* Creates a char pointer, and points this at i */
    char *c=(char*)&i;

    /* Overwrites the lowest byte of the 4 byte int with 1 */
    /* This sets the lowest bit of the int, which adds 1 */
    c[0]=1;

    /* Displays the updated int */
    cout<<"i is:"<<i<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Exactly which part of the int gets overwritten depends on the *endianness* of the platform you're compiling for. Given the final result of 513, your system is clearly little-endian.

Comment: You should probably qualify your explanation as applying specifically to little endian architectures.